# Create free spaces between elements inside wrapper

Tags: css

In CSS margins covers themselves for top and bottom margin. I need to reach this result for left end right.

--Edit--

Elements should be align to the left

Please see example:

```css
.a{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 12px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.b{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 12px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.c{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 12px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.root{
 display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
<div class="a">
</div>
<div class="b">
</div>
<div class="c">
</div>
</div>
```

In this case I need to have:

`.a` right margin for 12px

`.c` left margin for 12px

If there is just `.a` and `.b` I need to have:

`.a` right margin 12px.

If there would be `n` elements inside .root I need to have:

`.element1` right margin for 6px

`.element2` left and right margin for 6px

`.element3` left and right margin for 6px

`.element4` left and right margin for 6px

```
.....
```

`.elementn` left margin for 6px

Summary margin between elements should be 12px. But there should be no left margin for the first element and no right margin for the last element.

I show it how to do it manually, is it possible to set it in CSS if from CSS level I do not know how many element I will have?

Comment: Do you mean that you want left/right margins to collapse similarly to how top/bottom margins do in some browsers?

Comment: Yes, in at least Chrome and IE11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general I used JavaScript for count inside element and add correct class with number.

In CSS:

```
@margin: calc(@default_margin / 2);


   .row{
    margin: 0 @margin;
  }
  .row:first-child{
    margin-right: @margin;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .row:last-child{
    margin-left: @margin;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  .column-2{
    .row:first-child{
      margin-left: 0;
    }
    .row:last-child{
      margin-right: 0;
    }
  }
  .column-1{
    .row:first-child{
      margin: 0;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

This will do

```css
.root
{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
 }

.a{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 12px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.b{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 12px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.c{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 12px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.root{
 display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
<div class="a">
</div>
<div class="b">
</div>
<div class="c">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer, I forgot to mention, that elements should be align to the left.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer is to set half the margin you need for the each of children except the first.

There is no way to collapse horizontal margins. So if you want a 12px gap, you need to set a 6px left/right margin on all the children but have an extra 6px on the first element in the row.

```css
.a {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 6px 0 12px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.b {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 6px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.c {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 6px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.root {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="a">
  </div>
  <div class="b">
  </div>
  <div class="c">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What if inside .root div I have sometimes 1, 2 or 3 elements?

Comment: I don't understand your point...Perhaps you need to be clearer what it is you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Your answer was ok, but, you hardcode values. And it works only for 3 elements inside. But in my case, sometimes I need to put 2 divs inside .root and sometimes 3 divs. In case of 2 divs your answer will not work. I think I need to use javascript to solve this by adding specified classes depending of inside elements count.

Comment: To be fair, @MichałWojas you're adding new requirements that you did not specify in your question. You need to be specific. This answer is more than adequate to adjust to your needs.

Comment: It certainly does work with 2 children. - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/QMjxgx ...unless you still haven't explained what is **not** happening.

Comment: I have just edited the question. Hope it is precise now.